# Mystery coordinate offset on getCharBoundaries

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, text

I've ran into a weird problem with getCharBoundaries, I could not figure out what coordinate space the coordinates returned from the function was in. What ever I tried I could not get it to match up with what I expected.
So I made a new project and and added simple code to highlight the last charater in a textfield, and all of a sudden it worked fine. I then tried to copy over the TextField that had been causing me problems, into the new project. And now the same weird offset appeared 50px on the x axis. Everything else was spot on.
So after some headscracthing comparing the two TextFields, I simply can not see a difference in their properties or transformation.

So I was hoping that someone might now what property might affect the coordinates returned by getCharBoundaries.

I am using Flash CS4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just had exactly the same problem and thought I'd help out by offering what my findings are. With a help from this thread, I tried to find everything that wasn't 'default' about the textfield I was using. I found that when I had switched my TextFormatAlign (or 'align' in the IDE) and TextFieldAutoSize properties to 'LEFT' as opposed to 'CENTER', it solved the problem.

A little late in the game perhaps, but worth knowing for anyone running into the same problem. This was the only thread I could find that raised the right flag...

Comment: Sounds like that could be the answer. I'll give you the answer in case anyone comes by this question.

Answer (score 2):

Well the getCharBoundaries returns the boundaries in the textfield coordinate system. Where the origin is topleft corner of the textfield.
getCharBoundaries  does not take into consideration the scrolling.  you need to check if there are scrollbars on its parent (textarea) and if so relocate.  One quick way of doing it is using localtoglobal and globaltolocal.  Use the first to translate from the textfield coordinate system to the application coordinate system and then use the second to translate from the app coordinate system to the coordinate system of the parent of the textfield which is the textarea. I'm fine tuning a my method to get char boundaries i will publish it today on my blog 
http://flexbuzz.blogspot.com/

Comment: Good suggestion, but it was not the problem. But like I wrote it was a property on the TextField. Never found out which though.

Answer (score 0):

Works For Me(tm) (Flex Builder AS3 project):

```
[Embed(systemFont="Segoe UI", fontWeight="bold", fontName="emb",
    mimeType="application/x-font")]
private var EmbeddedFont:Class;

public function ScratchAs3()
{
    stage.scaleMode = 'noScale';
    stage.align = 'tl';

    var m:Matrix = new Matrix(.8, .1, -.1, 1.1, 26, 78);

    var t:TextField = new TextField();
    t.autoSize = 'left';
    t.wordWrap = false;
    t.embedFonts = true;
    t.defaultTextFormat = new TextFormat("emb", 100, 0, true);
    t.transform.matrix = m;
    t.text = "TEST STRING.";
    addChild(t);

    var r:Rectangle = t.getCharBoundaries(8);
    var tl:Point = m.transformPoint(r.topLeft);
    var tr:Point = m.transformPoint(new Point(r.right, r.top));
    var bl:Point = m.transformPoint(new Point(r.left, r.bottom));
    var br:Point = m.transformPoint(r.bottomRight);
    graphics.beginFill(0xFF, .6);
    graphics.moveTo(tl.x, tl.y);
    graphics.lineTo(tr.x, tr.y);
    graphics.lineTo(br.x, br.y);
    graphics.lineTo(bl.x, bl.y);
    graphics.lineTo(tl.x, tl.y);
}
```

To literally answer your question, it returns the coordinates in the TextField's coordinate system, not it's parent, and it is affected by DisplayObject.transform.matrix, which is the backing for the .x, .y, .scaleX, .scaleY, .width, .height, and .rotation properties.

Comment: I got the thing working with a new TextField, I just want to know what can affect the x coordinate returned.
I already checked scaling, and while that does effect the coordinates, it is not the cause here.

Answer (score 0):

What ever it was the solution was simple to add a new TextField, never found out what property screwed everything up.

Answer (score 0):

The first answer is correct in most cases. However if your field is parented to another movie clip it may still return the wrong y coordinate. try this code:

```
//if this doesn't work:

myTextFormat = new TextFormat();
myTextFormat.align = TextFormatAlign.LEFT; 
myFieldsParent.myField.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
myFieldsParent.myField.setTextFormat( myTextFormat);



//try this:
var x = myFieldsParent.myField.getCharBoundaries(o).x;
var y = myFieldsParent.myField.getCharBoundaries(o).y;

var myPoint:Point = new Point(myField.getCharBoundaries(o).x,myField.getCharBoundaries(o).y);

var pt:Point = new Point(myFieldsParent.myField.getCharBoundaries(o).x, myFieldsParent.myField.getCharBoundaries(o).y);
pt = myFieldsParent.myField.localToGlobal(pt);

//pt is the variable  containing the coordinates of the char in the stage's coordinate space. You may still need to offset it with a fixed value but it should be constant.
```

I didn't test this code as I have adapted this example from code that is embedded into my project so I apologize if I'm missing something...